# ETH contract FAILED "reverted" - what is the ETA?

Tags: contract-debugging, failed-transaction

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x03b22e12ee4a0c044bd7cd6c8b065134fb47e00bc9826884e14686ad03dff225

How long does it take for a contract "reverted" to return to place of origin?

Thank you for help

Comment: Hi Alexandre. Could you elaborate on what you mean by "return to place of origin"?

Comment: A reverted transaction means no changes have taken place, only fees were deducted from the sender. Some wallets unfortunately doesn't understand and they show as if the transaction was performed correctly you have reset the wallet or contact immediately the developers to fix the result.